# Problems with Android MIPS Architecture

Tags: gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I'm hoping someone can give me some help here.  I am new to Gluon-mobile and javafxports.  We are evaluating Gluon-mobile and are interested in using it on multiple architecture.  We are able to run the basic sample program on the Mac laptop and an Android Motorola phone.

However when we try to compile/deploy to an Android device with MIPS architecture we get the error message:

INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries.

Upon investigation,  it seems you get this error when you do not have the proper JNI libraries to support the CPU ABI instruction set on the machine you are deploying to.  When I unzip the apk file I see under the lib directory:

```
./armeabi
./armeabi/libactivity.so
./armeabi/libdecora_sse.so
./armeabi/libglass_monocle.so
./armeabi/libjavafx_font.so
./armeabi/libjavafx_font_freetype.so
./armeabi/libjavafx_iio.so
./armeabi/libprism_common.so
./armeabi/libprism_es2_monocle.so
./armeabi/libwebview.so
```

I believe these are the jni abi libs needed for arm abi.  I think we need the same set of libs for MIPS.

Is this supported in gluon/javafxports?

I looked for abi options in the gluon-mobile and javfxports doc but did not find any.

I tried placing this snippet in the build.gradle but it didn't work.

```
splits {
  abi {
   enable true
   reset()
   include 'mips', 'mips64'
   universalApk true
   }}
```

Any Ideas?

Thank you,

David

Comment: Quoting this [article](https://handstandsam.com/2016/01/28/determining-supported-processor-types-abis-for-an-android-device/), "I’ve never even heard of any modern android device using a “mips” based processor" and "“armeabi-v7a” is BY FAR [90%] the most widely seen ABI on Android]", what device are you using?

Comment: It is the MS200S and it supports Android 5.1.1.  Check out: ftp://ftp.ingenic.com/SOC/M200/M200S_DS.PDF. Your article has some good information.  When I execute ./adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist I get:  mips,mips which confirms the ABI.